# Installation of 12.04 on an usb stick

Tags: 12.04, dell, inspiron

I already booted in with the Usb stick, but when ever I try and open Ubuntu or even installing it goes to commands and says: invalid argument cannot mount. What does that mean? How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you attempted a live cd? What is your hardware? Have you ever installed linux on this machine? It seems to have a problem with your hd or your usb port. Are you able to boot or does it fail loading the initial usb session?

Answer (score 0):

It should go into the install automatically once you boot, you shouldn't have to "try and open Ubuntu" in any way, it should just.... Go.

Sometimes Ubuntu USB install doesn't work very well.  Try reformatting the USB and setting it up again, either with the live cd again, or with the alternate installer if that doesn't work.